# Cant understand nested lambdas in this function

Tags: python, lambda, nested, python-decorators

Can someone please explain to me how this nested lambdas + decorator work and what is the chronical
logic behind the output:

```
 amp = lambda f: lambda g:lambda x:g(f(f(x)))
    my_dec=amp(lambda x: "*"+x+"*")
    @my_dec
    def my_print(y):
        print(y)
    my_print("hello")
```

Answer (score 0):

That's a tricky one:

- `amp` is a function that takes another function `f` as parameter and return another funktion `g` taking a function `x` as parameter
- you call `amp` with `lambda x: "*"+x+"*"`, which is applied twice to the argument of the "innermost" function before passing it to the "middle" function; the result of that is your decorator `my_dec`
- that decorator is then applied to the `my_print` function, making `my_print` the `g` parameter in the `lambda g: ...` returned by `amp`
- finally, you pass `"hello"` to that decorated function, which is routed through `f` i.e. `lambda x: "*"+x+"*"` before being passed to `g` i.e. `my_print`

The whole thing becomes much clearer if you use proper `def` functions and longer parameter names (keeping the original `g`, `f`, and `x` for reference):

```
def amp(f_preproc):
    def my_parameterized_dec(g_function):
        def decorated_function(x_original_arg):
            new_arg = f_preproc(f_preproc(x_original_arg))
            return g_function(new_arg)
        return decorated_function
    return my_parameterized_dec

@amp(lambda x: "*"+x+"*")
def my_print(y):
    print(y)
```